# creating virtual library preparation of all possible exons in a gene of human

Tags: extract, fasta

I want to create a library for all possible exons in a gene for a human gene. This is not possible by gtf file which is available in Ensembl. Because I want to create mRNA of all possible combinations of exons and also exons and introns. I saw various platforms to searching this but didn't get any hit. So please can anyone help me to sort this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can anyone help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

I download the coordinates of all exons from biomart: It contains 5 columns 1st three are chromosome no., start exon, end exon. 4th column is transcript id, 5th column is exon rank.
10      100009838       100009947       ENST00000324109 1
10      99875577        99877336        ENST00000324109 17
10      99879811        99880361        ENST00000324109 16
10      99884011        99884209        ENST00000324109 15
10      99885687        99885866        ENST00000324109 14
10      99886300        99886632        ENST00000324109 13
10      99888825        99888953        ENST00000324109 12
10      99894946        99895050        ENST00000324109 11
10      99896267        99896397        ENST00000324109 10
10      99898086        99898285        ENST00000324109 9
10      99898743        99898760        ENST00000324109 8
10      99899919        99900066        ENST00000324109 7
10      99907995        99908094        ENST00000324109 6
10      99908953        99909146        ENST00000324109 5
10      99955214        99957205        ENST00000324109 4
10      99969115        99969237        ENST00000324109 3
10      99971980        99972134        ENST00000324109 2
10      100042193       100042573       ENST00000370418 9
10      100048758       100048876       ENST00000370418 8
10      100054347       100054446       ENST00000370418 7
10      100057013       100057152       ENST00000370418 6
10      100063614       100063725       ENST00000370418 5
10      100065188       100065370       ENST00000370418 4
10      100069714       100069869       ENST00000370418 3
10      100075911       100076107       ENST00000370418 2
10      100081403       100081869       ENST00000370418 1

So by these coordinates file can I make all possible combinations of whole genes and get in fasta format with different names.
Thanks in advance